# Insertion into AVL tree

Tags: c, tree, binary-tree, avl-tree

I am currently trying to construct a AVL tree in c where each node contains a name and a value. The tree should be sorted by value. Currently, with the input:

```
6 Franklin
4 David
1 Anna 
2 Bob
3 Cora
5 Ella
7 Griffin
```

the tree ends up looking like

```
         David
     /           \
   Anna        Franklin
      \        /    \
      Bob    Ella  Griffin
        \ 
       Cora
```

when it should look like

```
          David
      /          \
    Bob       Franklin
  /    \      /      \
Anna  Cora  Ella  Griffin
```

this seems to be the threshold size for it breaking, with input consisting of less nodes working.
relevant code:

```
#define MAX(X, Y) ((X) < (Y) ? (Y) : (X))

int height(struct Tree_Node *n) {

    if (n->right && n->left) return MAX(n->right->height, n->left->height) + 1;
    if (n->left && !n->right) return n->left->height + 1;
    if (n->right && !n->left) return n->right->height + 1;

    return 0;
}

int balance(struct Tree_Node *n) {

    if (n->left && n->right) return n->left->height - n->right->height;
    if (n->left && !n->right) return n->left->height;
    if (!n->left && n->right) return n->right->height;
    return 0;
}

struct Tree_Node *rotate_left(struct Tree_Node *n){

    struct Tree_Node *p;
    struct Tree_Node *tp;
    p = n;
    tp = p->left;

    p->left = tp->right;
    tp->right = p;

    return tp; 
}


struct Tree_Node *rotate_right(struct Tree_Node *n){

    struct Tree_Node *p;
    struct Tree_Node *tp;
    p = n;
    tp = p->right;

    p->right = tp->left;
    tp->left = p;

    return tp; 
}

struct Tree_Node *rotate_right_left(struct Tree_Node *n) {

    struct Tree_Node *p;
    struct Tree_Node *tp;
    struct Tree_Node *tp2;
    p = n;
    tp = p->right;
    tp2 =p->right->left;

    p -> right = tp2->left;
    tp ->left = tp2->right;
    tp2 ->left = p;
    tp2->right = tp; 
     
    return tp2; 
}

struct Tree_Node *rotate_left_right(struct Tree_Node *n) {

    struct Tree_Node *p;
    struct Tree_Node *tp;
    struct Tree_Node *tp2;
    p = n;
    tp = p->left;
    tp2 =p->left->right;

    p -> left = tp2->right;
    tp ->right = tp2->left;
    tp2 ->right = p;
    tp2->left = tp; 
     
    return tp2; 
}

struct Tree_Node *insert_leaf(struct Tree_Node *root, struct Tree_Node *new) {

    if (!root) {
        root = new;
        root->left = NULL;
        root->right = NULL;
        root->height = 0;
        return root;
    }
    else {
        if (new->value < root->value) root->left = insert_leaf(root->left, new);
        else root->right = insert_leaf(root->right, new);
    }
    root->height = height(root);
    
    if (balance(root) > 1 && new->value < root->left->value) root = rotate_left(root);
    else if (balance(root) < -1 && new->value > root->right->value) root = rotate_right(root);
    else if (balance(root) < -1 && new->value < root->right->value) root = rotate_right_left(root);
    else if (balance(root) > 1 && new->value > root->left->value) root = rotate_left_right(root);

    return root;
}
```

Comment: Rethink `if (!n->left && n->right) return n->right->height;` in `balance`.

Comment: Edit the problem to provide a [mre]. Even if the problem is simply the issue I point out above, a MRE would make it easy for me to test this causes the results you report, to confirm it is the only cause, or to explore the code’s behavior. You should always provide a MRE when asking for debugging help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are the following issues:

- The height of a leaf node is 1, not 0. So the last `return` in the `height` function should be:

  ```
  return 1;
  ```

  And in the `insert_leaf` function, remove these two lines from the `if` block:

  ```
  root->height = 0;
  return root;
  ```

  That way the execution will continue with a call to `height` to set this value correctly to 1.
- The rotation functions will change the height of node(s) that are descendant(s) of the returned node, so you must update their height(s). In the single rotation functions, add therefore this line:

  ```
  p->height = height(p);
  ```

  And in the double rotation functions, add:

  ```
  p->height = height(p);
  tp->height = height(tp);
  ```
- You define the balance for a right-heavy tree as negative with `n->left->height - n->right->height`, but then make it *positive* when `n->left` is `NULL` and `n->right` is not. It should be *negative* in that case. So add the negation operator like this:

  ```
  if (!n->left && n->right) return -n->right->height;
  ```

With these changes the expected tree will be built for your test case.